# Equality of combinations of exponentials and logarithms

Tags: transcendental-number-theory, decidability

Suppose I have some combination of exponentials, logarithms, and arithmetic operations on rational numbers. For example, $e^{e^{r_1} + \log r_2} - r_3$. Under what conditions does an algorithm exist for determining when the expression is exactly 0?

For the example above, I can reduce into some normal form, such as $r_2 e^{e^{r_1}} - r_3$, and then it is nonzero by the Gelfond-Schneider theorem, but I am not sure the same technique would work in all cases. For example, it is not clear to me how to handle a case with both double and single exponentiation.

Comment: Are the rationals taken as given, or as variables?

Comment: The rationals are concrete—no variables. So there's no question of quantifiers or anything like that.

Comment: Maybe there's something of interest in Richardson and Fitch, The identity problem for elementary functions and constants, ISSAC '94 Proceedings of the international symposium on Symbolic and algebraic computation, Pages 285 - 290, which is available on the web.

Comment: If that paper leads you to an answer to your question, maybe you could post it as an answer here.

Comment: The paper is... dense. I'll try to figure it out; if I do, I'll post an explanation.